# Why is my function mutating the parameter even though I written it as a pure function?

Tags: python, python-2.7

This function adds a zero to each item in the list.

```
def add_column(matrix):
"""
  >>> m = [[0, 0], [0, 0]]
  >>> add_column(m)
  [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
  >>> n = [[3, 2], [5, 1], [4, 7]]
  >>> add_column(n)
  [[3, 2, 0], [5, 1, 0], [4, 7, 0]]
  >>> n
  [[3, 2], [5, 1], [4, 7]]
"""
    new_list=matrix[:]
    for i in range(len(new_list)):
        new_list[i].append(0)
    return new_list
```

It's changing the parameter that I pass it rather than creating a new object of it.
How do I make it so that I get the expected results?

```
>>> n = [[3, 2], [5, 1], [4, 7]]
>>> g = add_column(n)
```

**Expected:**

```
>>> print n
[[3, 2], [5, 1], [4, 7]]

>>> print g
[[3, 2, 0], [5, 1, 0], [4, 7, 0]]
```

**Actual Result:**

```
>>> print n
[[3, 2, 0], [5, 1, 0], [4, 7, 0]]

>>> print g
[[3, 2, 0], [5, 1, 0], [4, 7, 0]]
```

Comment: Please properly format your code.

Comment: You should search around. This list behavior is honestly one of the most frequently asked questions on the Python tag and is discussed in every Python tutorial I can think of.

Comment: I didn't know well enough how to phrase my question to find the answer. But duly noted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`[:]` only creates a *shallow* copy of a list.  You need to use [`copy.deepcopy`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy) and create a deep copy:

```
from copy import deepcopy

def add_column(matrix):  
...
    new_list=deepcopy(matrix)
```

For more information, see this Wikipedia article on [object copying](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_copy).

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to make a pure function by copying the matrix with `new_list=matrix[:]`. However, that only makes a shallow copy, so each sublist will still be a reference to the corresponding sublist in the original matrix. One way you can avoid this is by replacing the line `new_list[i].append(0)` with `new_list[i] = new_list[i] + [0]`, which will make a copy of the inner list.

However, this problem is more simply solved with a list comprehension, which will automatically create a new list:

```
def add_column(matrix):
    return [sublist+[0] for sublist in matrix]
```